After updating to Confluent 7.5 brokers can no longer connect to Zookeeper
The goal is to update the Kafka cluster to version 7.6 in order to migrate to Karft.
A few key facts about the cluster:

No Docker / Podman
3 ZooKeeper (single VMs in vSphere)
3 brokers (individual VMs in vSphere)
Openjdk 11 (also tested with open-jdk 17)
CentOS 8

First of all a short history:
We currently have Consulent 7.3. I wanted to update from 7.3 to 7.6 but unfortunately this did not work. Same error as I will describe in a moment. Because after a long time it was not clear where the problems came from, I downgraded to 7.3 and everything works again. Then I updated to 7.4 and everything continued to work. Then I tried to update to version 7.5. This was no problem with ZooKeepers. They start and can also communicate with each other. The brokers of version 7.4 can communicate with the ZooKeepers of version 7.5 without any problems. However, as soon as I update the first broker to version 7.5, it can no longer talk to the ZooKeepers and I simply don't understand why.
Both Broker and ZooKeeper use SSL with Key & Truststore. As I said, up to version 7.4 this works without any problems.
Now for the error.
I get the following message in the Zookeeper log when the 7.5 broker tries to establish a connection.
zookeeper-server.log:
[2024-04-12 11:03:55,479] INFO Committing global session 0x1000faf33940136    (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerSessionTracker)
[2024-04-12 11:03:55,484] INFO Submitting global closeSession request for session 0x1000faf33940136 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-12 11:03:55,740] INFO Committing global session 0x30022c77eb20369 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerSessionTracker)
[2024-04-12 11:22:53,966] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 11:24:37,220] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 11:24:45,603] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 11:46:51,209] INFO Purge task started. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 11:46:51,209] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2024-04-12 11:46:51,210] INFO Purge task completed. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 12:46:50,830] INFO Purge task started. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 12:46:50,830] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2024-04-12 12:46:50,831] INFO Purge task completed. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 12:46:53,530] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 12:48:35,950] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 12:58:44,424] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 12:59:27,398] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 13:01:02,642] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 13:46:50,898] INFO Purge task started. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 13:46:50,898] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2024-04-12 13:46:50,899] INFO Purge task completed. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 14:44:56,454] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 14:46:50,831] INFO Purge task started. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 14:46:50,832] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2024-04-12 14:46:50,833] INFO Purge task completed. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-04-12 15:16:55,472] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 15:17:48,896] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-12 15:17:58,445] ERROR Unsuccessful handshake with session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)

However, the broker reports a different error:
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,029] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper2.domain.de/XX.XX.XX.XX:2182. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,094] INFO SSL handler added for channel: [id: 0x34aaf58e] (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,094] WARN future isn't success. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.channel.unix.Errors
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:351)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:773)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.doConnect0(EpollSocketChannel.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:758)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:600)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:653)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:632)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.connect(SslHandler.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:657)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:632)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:616)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:978)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:265)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$3.run(Bootstrap.java:264)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:413)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,099] INFO channel is told closing (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,103] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,104] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,109] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:116)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2266)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2253)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.createZkClient(KafkaZkClient.scala:2358)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:634)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:221)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:113)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2024-04-12 15:16:19,117] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:116)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2266)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2253)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.createZkClient(KafkaZkClient.scala:2358)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:634)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:221)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:113)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

part from zookeeper.properties (zookeeper)
secureClientPort=2182

maxClientCnxns=0
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
autopurge.snapRetainCount=10
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
dataDir=/data/zookeeper/
4lw.commands.whitelist=*

serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
#clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
authProvider.x509=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.X509AuthenticationProvider
ssl.keyStore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/zookeeper.keystore.jks
ssl.keyStore.password=secret
ssl.trustStore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/zookeeper.truststore.jks
ssl.trustStore.password=secret

admin.enableServer=False

server.1=zookeeper1.domain.de:2888:3888
server.2=zookeeper2.domain.de:2888:3888
server.3=zookeeper3.domain.de:2888:3888

sslQuorum=True
portUnification=True
ssl.quorum.keyStore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/zookeeper.keystore.jks
ssl.quorum.keyStore.password=Secret
ssl.quorum.trustStore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/zookeeper.truststore.jks
ssl.quorum.trustStore.password=Secret


part from server.properties (broker)
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1.domain.de:2182,zookeeper2.domain.de:2182,zookeeper3.domain.de:2182/kafka
zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
# Define trust store to use TLS to ZooKeeper; ignored unless zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/broker.truststore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password=secret
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=/var/ssl/private/kafka/broker.keystore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=secret

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=30000

log.dirs=/data/broker
broker.id=1

default.replication.factor=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas=2

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=336
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
num.io.threads=16
num.network.threads=8
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=2
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
min.insync.replicas=2
replica.lag.max.messages=4
replica.lag.time.max.ms=20000
replica.socket.timeout.ms=60000
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=10000
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=15
auto.create.topics.enable=False
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=False

ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^CN= *************************** DEFAULT
super.users=User:kafka;
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer

listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:SSL,INTERNAL:SSL
listeners=EXTERNAL://broker1.domain.de:9092,INTERNAL://broker1.domain.de:9091
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://broker1.domain.de:9092,INTERNAL://broker1.domain.de:9091
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
inter.broker.protocol.version=3.3
...
...
...
...


Something must have changed between version 7.4 and 7.5 which I have not found. Can anyone give me a hint?
Thank you in advance!
